# Are my container's children starting at index -1 or 0?

Tags: flex3

I'm getting some behavior with a container object's children I just don't understand.

I'm making four display objects children of an `mx:Canvas` object.  When I call `getChildren()`, I see them all in order, right where I think they should be:

```
1
2
3
4
```

The fun begins when I call `swapChildrenAt(0,1)`; that's supposed to swap the positions of `1` and `2`, but instead I wind up with:

```
MYSTERY_OBJECT_OF_MYSTERY
2
3
4
```

So, where did `1` go?  Why, it's at position -1, of course.

```
getChildAt(-1): 1
getChildAt(0): MYSTERY_OBJECT_OF_MYSTERY
getChildAt(1): 2
getChildAt(2): 3
getChildAt(3): 4
```

FWIW, `MYSTERY_OBJECT_OF_MYSTERY` is a 'border'.  Don't know how it got there.

Regardless, I find it baffling that `getChildAt()` and `swapChildrenAt()` are apparently using different starting indexes.  Can anybody shed some light on this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be swapping the index of the display Objects instead of passing the display Objects at those location themselves.

The official documentation says 
"`swapChildren(child1:DisplayObject, child2:DisplayObject):void`" therefore the index of the Display Objects themselves cant be used.

I hope this solves your problem.